# WPF - How to populate TreeView with directory path strings

Tags: wpf, treeview

I can't find a solution to add `TreeViewItem`s to a WPF  TreeView hierarchically. Each string is as follows:

`\\localhost\C$\Application\<ServiceN>\folder\file.doc`

If there are multiple strings with the same `<ServiceN>`, I would like them to be added under the same ServiceN `TreeViewItem`. I would like to display the items like this:

`localhost
    ServiceN
        C$\Application\ServiceN\folder
            file.doc
            file2.doc
    ServiceN2
        C$\Application\ServiceN2\folder
            fileN.doc`

So far, I have tried by using a List with a `ItemsSource` like this:

```
BindingList<string> treeItems = new BindingList<string>();
listView.ItemsSource = treeItems;
```

elsewhere in the code:

```
foreach(string f in paths) {
    treeItems.Add(f);
}
```

However, that will display the items as simple string items without any depth/level. I also used multiple nested for loops, but that does not seem as the most efficient way. How can I parse each path string and add it into the correct TreeView position?

Comment: Follow this [hierarchial data binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd759035%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) tutorial

Comment: When I add the `<StackPanel.Resources>` part in XAML, I get the error "The member Resources is not recognized or is not accessible".

Comment: I have added the TreeView items using multiple `HierarchicalDataTemplate` items for each level. But sometimes the level changes, it gets bigger because I need to add an extra item. The `HierarchicalDataTemplate` implies a fixed structure.. how can I add an extra level in between the items during runtime?